# Return mongoose query result

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose aggregate query which I want to return its result calling it inside a function. I have tried to make the function async but is returning a pending promise.

**My function**

```
getCurrentBollinger = async (country, company) => {
    const aggregateData = await MarketModel.aggregate([
            .
            .
            .
        ])
        .limit(69)
        .sort({
            _id: 1
        })
        .exec();

    return aggregateData;
}
```

How can I return the results?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the above code. Please show where you call `getCurrentBollinger`

Comment: @Ashh I'm just calling like this to print the result console.log(getCurrentBollinger('Spain', 'ACS'))

Comment: `getCurrentBollinger` is an async function you need to use .then to get the result from it.  Something like this `getCurrentBollinger('Spain', 'ACS').then((data) => { console.log(data) })`

Comment: Oh thanks, don't know what I was thinking about